# Light gallery match error

Tags: jquery, gallery, lightgallery

I'm making a video gallery with light gallery plugin in time to run it generates the following error Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'match' of undefined, as researched in forums but not yet encotrei a solution.

Test Page:

```
var youtube = src.match(/\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=|embed\/)?([a-z0-9self\-]+)/i);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joseferreira/37cgt6jq/

Comment: What code do you have already?

Comment: Looks like you cannot apply ``match`` to ``src``. What is ``src``?

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong html markup.

Use like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="lightgallery">
<a href="images/landding/1.jpg" class="light-link">
  <img src="images/landding/1.jpg" />
</a>
 <a href="images/landding/1.jpg" class="light-link">
  <img src="images/landding/1.jpg" />
</a>
 <a href="images/landding/1.jpg" class="light-link">
  <img src="images/landding/1.jpg" />
</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#lightgallery").lightGallery({
       selector: '.light-link'
    });
```